# row_number query in Dask with SQLAlchemy 1.3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask

I am trying to get SQLAlchemy to create the following standard SQL query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(select 0)) AS row_num, User_Id FROM my_table
```

Using the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, func, Column, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

/* engine details */

metadata = MetaData()

t = Table('my_table', metadata, Column('User_Id'))

sql_query = select([func.row_number().over(order_by=select([0])).label('row_num'), t])

/* run sql query code */
```

However I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS row_num, my_table.[User_Id] 
FROM (SELECT 0), my_table]
```

I assume it is because of the `FROM (SELECT 0), my_table` part of the query. How can I remove `(SELECT 0)` from the FROM statement in my `sql_query`?

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? I just tried your code with SQLA 1.4.34 and it generated the SELECT statement with just `FROM my_table`, so SQL Server didn't throw an error. (However, I did get a couple of deprecation warnings from SQLA itself.)

Comment: I am using version 1.3.20 as I need to connect to Denodo and their dialect doesn't work with anything newer - could it be the version that is throwing the error?

Comment: Issue reproduced with SQLA 1.3.20 and 1.3.24. How about `sql_query = select([func.row_number().over(order_by=t.c.User_Id).label('row_num'), t])` as an alternative?

Comment: So that seems to have passed through, but now I get the error `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'subquery'` - I should explain I am trying to load in large sql data into a dask dataframe and set the index col of the dask dataframe to row number (as the user ID is string based)

Comment: I tested using `mssql+pyodbc://` and `results = conn.execute(sql_query).fetchall()` worked fine for me. What dialect are you using?

Comment: I am using `mssql+pyodbc` - I think it may be dask itself trying to manipulate the query under the hood as I get these errors:

`venv\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\sql.py", line 421, in read_sql
return read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, **kwargs)`

`venv\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\sql.py", line 135, in read_sql_query
    ).select_from(sql.subquery())`

`AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'subquery'`

So whatever it is doing under the hood is causing it to throw that error. I just want to load in the row_num so I can split the dataframes

Comment: It looks like you are using a relatively current version of Dask (released after [this PR](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/8158)). You may need to downgrade your Dask if you need to stay on SQLA 1.3.

Comment: Indeed, dask's SQL reader was updated recently to cope with changes in SQLA; it was supposed to be backward compatible, but pyodbc-mysql is not typical for us.

Comment: is there a better configuration I can use? I am trying to compare 2 large datasets with the df.eq(df2).all().compute() method but as the index column needs to be set to a string type (even though it is all numbers but set as string in the DB) I am trying to figure out how best to work this. I need to run through multiple comparisons between the 2 systems to make sure all data matches. However, dask when using a string index_col and setting divisions=list('0123456789'), it seems the index length is less than the row count, even though there are no nulls in the column used for the index_col

Comment: I thought by bring in row_number as part of the sql query, dask would have a number based index_col to use for automatic partitions, but I just can't seem to get it working